# Input Start Date and End Date to MYSQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a webpage where users can input the start & end date and time for the DIV to appear. After it reaches the end date, the DIV will be deactivated until the users have input another start and end date and time. I have start date and end date column in my MYSQL database. How do I start ? Any hints? Or maybe better suggestions on how this works.

These are the requirements: 
- Must allow the questionnaire to be released for a fixed time period
- Should allow the questionnaire to be issued more than once.

Comment: Show the code that you have tried till now

Comment: Could you give more details about your exact requirement?

Comment: @Zword I just started , and I'm not sure how to. So I need some hints on how to start. Well I think I'll try it out first.

Comment: @NgmAKumar Updated with the requirements.

Comment: Do you want to same user to be able to access the div only once or multiple times? If once you could use a timer from the date activated of X amount of days etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php 
This will give you an idea. When you have your code you can come back to this site and ask concrete questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){         
  $("#YOUR_DIV_ID").hide();         
}, 60000);
```

You can use setInterval using JQuery to hide your DIV I have given 1 minute interval, Else you can remove your div using:

```
$("#YOUR_DIV_ID").remove();
```

This is the one of easy way.